# How to separate specific chunks of input stream?

Tags: java, batch-processing

Suppose I am getting a stream of data from a text file in the format:

```
A,some values 
B,some values 
C,some values
C,some values
D,some values
D,some values
A,some values
B,some values....and so on
```

How do I separate from A to last D in single chunk process and then again come back for next chunk?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the `some values` on each row?

Comment: Basically, you're going to keep track of whether a D is followed by an A, or something like that, which means storing the previous "key" in a variable so you can look at it when you read the next key.  Past that, you haven't given us nearly enough details.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:these some values are long enough and are properties associated with ID 'A,B,C' and so on.

Comment: @ajb,yes you are wright,but buffered reader has a small problem,once I do readline the next line is poped out from the buffer.but at this time I also came to know that my first lot has ended and i need to process it.

Comment: Do you want a solution as a (Windows) batch file, or are you looking for a Java program to do that? Both tags together seems rather strange

Comment: Maybe the batch file calls an executable Java JAR ^ ^ ... Let's work overtime on this one.

Comment: when the ID changes from D to A,we get to know that the new chunk has started,but how to restore that one new line of the next chunk back to the buffered reader?